# change values of column to consecutive integers

Tags: r, database, format, rename, data-cleaning

I have a CSV where the first column is my subject ID number,
there's a total of 311 subjects, and on average 1000 values per subject.
The subject ID numbers are quite random (although integers only) ranging from 72 to 2265988.
What I would like to do is neatly rename them to numbers 1-311.

What would be the quickest way to do this in R, preferably, or in excel?

Comment: *in R, preferably, or in excel* - yet you have tagged neither.

Comment: I have a tag for 'R'

Comment: In R, you can create a vector `new_ID <- seq(1, 311)`, then you sort the existing ID column from smaller to the highest value. Finally, you replace this column with a newly created vector.

Comment: That's a simple but adequate solution, thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Bloxx I now realize it may not be as simple as this; I have many repetitions of each ID, so how do I ensure repeated measures are assigned the same ID from the 1-311 sequence?

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is your solution. You just replace with your names:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,3,5,3,6,7),
             var = c(3,6,8,5,7,8))             

temp <- data.frame(old_id = sort(unique(df$ID)),
              new_id =seq(1,5))

replace_ID <-  temp$new_id[match(df$ID, temp$old_id)]
df$ID <- replace_ID
df
```

Comment: in the 4th line you have to put  `new_ID = seq(1, 311) `